# Renaming documents in folders Issue- PowerShell

Tags: powershell

hopefully someone can assist with an issue i am having with my PS script.

the over all goal is to rename ONLY images that come into a directly of multiple folders and then move them to another folder with a set naming convention, my code is below, whenever i run the code, the image files are moving as expected but majority of the images names are being duplicated lots in the file name which is causing the max character error.

---

```
# Source directory
$srcdir = "<Source Directory>"

# Output directory
$opdir = "<output directory>"

# Loop through source directory and list folders only - store in variable $folders
$folders = Get-ChildItem $srcdir | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

# Cycle through each directory within in source directory and process
foreach ($dir in $folders) {

    # Set PS working directory
    Set-Location $srcdir\$dir

            # JPG Files
            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name }

            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Move-Item -Destination ($opdir)

            # JPEG Files
            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpeg | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name }

            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpeg | Move-Item -Destination ($opdir)

            # PNG Files
            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name }

            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png | Move-Item -Destination ($opdir)

            # GIF Files
            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.gif | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name }

            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.gif | Move-Item -Destination ($opdir)

            # TIFF Files
            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.tiff | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name }

            Get-ChildItem -Filter *.tiff | Move-Item -Destination ($opdir)

            Write-Host "`nAll images renamed and moved from directory: " $srcdir\$dir

            # Move remaining files to servers Recycle Bin
            del *.*

            Write-Host "Deleted remaining files from: " $srcdir\$dir

            Set-Location $srcdir

            Write-Host "Switched to directory: " $srcdir

            rmdir $srcdir\$dir

            Write-Host "Deleted directory: " $srcdir\$dir "`n"

        }


Write-Host "`n`n*****************************************"
Write-Host "Script has finished executing..."
Write-Host "*****************************************"
```

---

Errors:

> ```
> Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
> At C:\Users\admin.ph\Desktop\FileMover.ps1:17 char:43
> + ... ter *.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName {"Y1" + $dir.replace('.3', '.5') + " ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\admin.....5_00427993.jpg:String) [Rename-Item], Direct 
>    oryNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should in principle do what you want if $folders is filled as expected. But I am not sure if thats the case, as the current code posted is missing _ after the dollar, working version:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $srcdir | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

btw. you could shorten this a bit:

```
$srcdir = [path]

#Get folders as whole object so you do not need to build the sourcePath, also no need to pipe and filter with where-object
$folders = Get-ChildItem $srcdir -Directory 
foreach ($dir in $folders){
    #Add try/catch to ensure that if something goes wrong you won't delete the folder
    try {
        #add "\*" to path to support wildcards for -include parameter; add -passthru to rename-item to get the new path back and add -erroraction:stop to ensure any error is a terminating error
        $renamedItems = Get-ChildItem -Path ($dir.FullName + "\*") -include @('*.jpg','*.png','*.jpeg','*.tiff','*.gif') | Rename-Item -NewName ("Y1" + $dir.name.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name) -PassThru -ErrorAction:Stop
    }
    Catch {
        write-error "Failed to rename item, abort processing - Exception: $_"
        #If something fails processes next item             
        continue
    }
    try {
        #parameter -path supports array so you can passover the path of all renamed items
        $null = move-item -Path $renamedItems.FullName -Destination $opdir -ErrorAction:Stop
    }
    Catch {
        write-error "Failed to move item, abort processing - Exception: $_"
        #If something fails processes next item             
        continue        
    }
    #removes the folder and its content/substructure, if you only want to remove the files replace $dir.FullName with renamedItems.FullName
    $null = remove-item -path $dir.FullName -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

If you sill have to face the issue please verify that `("Y1" + $dir.name.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name)` produces the expected result.

Comment: Hi Toni, thanks for getting back to me!

i have copied the code and I'm getting the below now when i run it?

FileMoverv2.ps1 : An Exception occured, abort processing - Exception: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,FileMoverv2.ps1

thanks again!

Comment: ok maybe the file already exists at the target location from earlier tries? I'll modify the error handling later that we know where exactly the error happens

Comment: Hi Toni, thanks so much for your help, i managed to resolve it by changing Rename-Item -NewName ("Y1" + $dir.name.replace('.3', '.5') + "_" + $_.Name) to {_____}